# actionscript 3 position textfield N pixels from bottom or 90% from top

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I'm new to actionscript 3.  I want to create a textfield that is either N number of pixels from the bottom of the stage or 90% from the top of the stage.

Basically i want the textfield to always appear near the bottom of the stage.  What property of the TextField() object do I configure to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function updateTextPosition():void
{
    var newPositionY:Number = (stage.stageHeight * .90);
    myTextField.y = newPositionY;
}
```

Now if you want to account for the height of the actual text for whatever reason, you change it to this:

```
function updateTextPosition():void
{
    var newPositionY:Number = (stage.stageHeight * .90) - myTextField.textHeight;
    myTextField.y = newPositionY;
}
```

Remember the origin of the field is top left, so the bottom of the text will appear at `myTextField.x + myTextField.textHeight;`.

Also, you can listen for the RESIZE event on the stage and update your TextField like so:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResized);

function onStageResized(e:Event):void
{
    updateTextPosition();
}
```

Comment: thank you.  I got spoiled by CSS and assumed i could do things like textfield.bottom = 10px or textfield.top = 20%

Comment: @John you can but I can't think of a way to set both constraints without doing some AS3, you can use bottom = 10 but then it has to be in a container that has an absolute layout, otherwise you can put it in a container that has a layout that fits your needs in general then use a spacer if necessary to create a gap between components.

Comment: ok great.  how come when i hit full screen for my movie player, stage.height still show 416px?  But when i resize the `<object>` tag to height 515px, then stage.height shows 515px?  Does full screen not qualify as Event.resize?  Or does stage object not apply to full screen?

Comment: stage.stageHeight not .height. Same with width, it's stage.stageWidth

Comment: bam! it worked.  I am so awesome.   I mean...you guys are so awesome.